# `use std::error::Error` declaration breaks compilation

Tags: rust

I wrote a small function to log whole stack traces which looks like this:

```
fn report_error(error: &Box<dyn std::error::Error>, message: &str) {
    let mut error_msg = Vec::<String>::new();
    error_msg.push(message.to_string());
    if let Some(source) = error.source() {
        error_msg.push("caused by:".into());
        for (i, e) in std::iter::successors(Some(source), |e| e.source()).enumerate() {
            error_msg.push(format!("\t{}: {}", i, e));
        }
    }
    tracing::error!("{}", error_msg.join("\n"));
}
```

This codes compiles and runs fine with rustc 1.67.1. Compilation fails though as soon as I add a `use std::error::Error;` declaration at the top, with this error:

```
   Compiling playground v0.0.1 (/playground)
error: lifetime may not live long enough
 --> src/lib.rs:8:63
  |
8 |         for (i, e) in std::iter::successors(Some(source), |e| e.source()).enumerate() {
  |                                                            -- ^^^^^^^^^^ returning this value requires that `'1` must outlive `'2`
  |                                                            ||
  |                                                            |return type of closure is Option<&'2 dyn std::error::Error>
  |                                                            has type `&'1 &dyn std::error::Error`

error: could not compile `playground` due to previous error
```

I've got no clue about why this happens. It's not like importing `Error` explicitly changes the declared types in any way here, right? How is this possible?

Here's a link to the Rust Playground demonstrating this code:
https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=400c01faf36c3ada21d875ce3b6ec0a4

Comment: I'm not sure `successors` is the right approach here, as trying to chain references through that may not work. Could you use a more straight-forward recursive approach?

Comment: @tadman I'm totally new to Rust so I'm open to any feedback. I can say though that when I comment out that `use` declaration my code not only compiles but seems to work as intended as well.

Comment: I could definitely use a `while let` to process all sources, but especially since I'm still learning I wanted to understand what the issue is here.

Comment: This seems very weird, but it's actually logical. It happens because `Box<dyn Error>` dereferences to the inner imlementation of `Error` and will use that implementation's `source()` method. But!- when you bring the `Error` trait into scope, it will instead call the `source()` method on the the `Error` impl for `Box<E>` (where `E: Error`).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This seems initially very confusing!

Without the import, when you call `source()` on the `Box<dyn Error>`, Rust follows a [set of rules](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/expressions/method-call-expr.html) to find the right method to call, and ends up dereferencing the `Box` to call the method on its contents.

However, when you import `std::error::Error`, you bring the trait into scope. This changes things because there is an [implementation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/error/trait.Error.html#impl-Error-for-Box%3CT%2C%20Global%3E) of `Error` for `&E where E: Error`.

The method you want to call (without `Error` being in scope)  effectively has this signature:

```
fn source<'e>(err: &'e dyn Error) -> Option<&'e (dyn Error + 'static)>
```

Notice that the lifetime of the reference in the return value is connected to the lifetime of the trait object in the argument. If you chain many calls to `source()` together, the lifetime of the last one will still be connected to the first.

But the method you are actually calling has this signature:

```
fn source<'e, 'x>(err: &'e &'x dyn Error) -> Option<&'e (dyn Error + 'static)>
```

So, when you call `source()`, the result is not connected to the object in the argument by lifetimes: instead it's connected to a *reference* to the object. When you use this in a recursive iterator, these lifetimes expire within each iteration.

You can "fix" the issue, by explicitly dereferencing the box so that it is forced to call the method on the inner value:

```
for (i, e) in std::iter::successors(Some(source), |e| (&**e).source()).enumerate() {
     error_msg.push(format!("\t{}: {}", i, e));
}
```

This works as it originally did, even if you import `std::error::Error`, because there is no ambiguity about which implementation of `Error` we mean.

Alternatively, you could use a loop instead of recursion.

Comment: thanks, but I'm still trying to wrap my head around one last thing. The issue of calling another function is now clear thanks to your explanation, but I still don't get why that breaks my lifetime: aren't all of these (different) implementors referring to the same trait with the same signature? Apparently not, but I cannot see the difference yet.

Comment: Heh, this crossed my mind as I was writing, but it is after midnight here and I will look again with a fresh mind tomorrow - unless someone else throws in the explanation in the meantime :)

Comment: I took a look and its actually not the implementation on `Box`, but rather the [implementation on `&T where T: Error`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/error/trait.Error.html#impl-Error-for-%26%27a%20T) that is the problem. Since `e` in this case is `&&dyn Error`, importing the trait means the returned source is bound to the lifetime of the first reference and without it is bound to the second reference.

Comment: @kmdreko so: `successors()` takes a closure of the form `FnMut(&T) -> Option<T>`, where `T` is my `&dyn Error` from the `if let`, and  `e` becomes `&'1 &dyn Error`: calling `e.source()` I implicitly dereference `e` just once, ending up with invoking the implementation for `&'2 dyn Error`  (which is the `&T where T: Error`). `'1` ends with the closure itself, therefore it can't outlive `'2`. If I dereference `e` even once, `|e| (*e).cause()`, then the `.source()` implicitly dereferences it again and obtains the correct trait implementation, binding its lifetime to `source` instead.  Right?